# I'm trying to export something as FBX, but the point instances from Geometry Nodes don't get imported

Tags: export, geometry-nodes

I recently made a model in Blender that I wish to export, but only the base shape without the Point Instances gets exported. I've tried to look for fixes but none of them have worked. I have tried `obj`, `fbx`, `stl`, `glb`, `x3d` and `ply` so far but none of them have the expected outcome with the Point Instances. I also can't apply the Geometry Nodes modifier as the Point Instances have a different colour than the parent object and when I tried applying it they inherited the parent colour.

Comment: Add a geometry nodes modifier at the end of the stack, and simply plug a "realize instances" node there. Then copy it to all the objects that use instanced geometry via geometry nodes

Comment: To get a more detail answer it might be helpful to attach your blend file or an example of it.  You can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to attach files.

Comment: I'll try the Realise Instances node and fix any part of the model that is from 2.93 which is the version I had made the model in and posted this question with, it took a while to respond as I was busy and I also had to download Blender 3.1.

Comment: After I used the Realise Instances, the colour of the instances weren't the same as the one in the Shading tab from when I made the texture for them, and the base instance is the only one with the proper colour.